# Groovy: Get value with key from a string array

Tags: string, groovy

I have a variable named 'output' which is string array which holds a comma separated key value pairs. What's the best way to parse it to retrieve the value e.g.'arm64-v8a' using it's key 'ro.product.cpu.abi'?

```
       String[] output= androidDetails();
       println("Output is $output")

//prints
//Output is [[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a], [ro.product.manufacturer]: //[Google], [ro.product.model]: [Pixel 2], [ro.product.name]: [walleye]]
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand; there isn’t much to parse, you’d just do a string compare. Might be easier to fix the “androidDetails” method so it doesn’t return what looks to be a string representation of a map, though.

Comment: @tim_yates the androidDetails() method is not something I can easily change but the contents of the array are shown in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works to parse the data held in the variable 'output' (contents in the question) into a map with the correct key values.

```
String outputString = output.toString()
                outputString=outputString.replace("[","")
                outputString=outputString.replace("]","")
                outputString=outputString.replace(" ","")
                outputString="["+outputString+"]"
                println("outputString" + outputString.toString())
                def map =
                        // Take the String value between
                        // the [ and ] brackets.
                        outputString[1..-2]
                        // Split on , to get a List.
                                .split(',')
                        // Each list item is transformed
                        // to a Map entry with key/value.
                                .collectEntries { entry ->
                                    def pair = entry.split(':')
                                    [(pair.first()): pair.last()]
                                }

                println("map.size" +map.size())
                println("map.ro.product.cpu.abi " +map['map.ro.product.cpu.abi]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn that string relatively easy into a map, then you can pick from that what you want.  E.g.

```
def data = '[[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a], [ro.product.manufacturer]: [Google], [ro.product.model]: [Pixel 2], [ro.product.name]: [walleye]]'

def parsed = (data =~ /\[([a-z\.]+?)\]\s*:\s*\[(.*?)\]/).iterator().collectEntries{ _, k, v -> [k,v] }

assert parsed['ro.product.cpu.abi'] == 'arm64-v8a'
```